# Do we really need to use Interlocked for global int variables?

Tags: c#, .net

My question is based on this article https://www.harshmaurya.in/volatile-vs-lock-vs-interlocked-in-c-net/
where it shows an example:

```
private int _counter = 0;
```

and suppose you have multiple threads that do `_counter++;`

The article suggests to use Interlocked class like `Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);`

I can understand why Interlocked is needed to ensure writng a value to a variable is atomic operation because a single line of C# code is three steps (three line of CPU instructions) in processor, so if the write operations are not atomic, each thread can interleave, which wrongly overwrite the final result.

But I also read the book CLR via C# which says:

> The CLR guarantees that reads and writes to variables of the following data types are atomic: Boolean,
> Char, (S)Byte, (U)Int16, (U)Int32, (U)IntPtr, Single, and reference types. This means that
> all bytes within that variable are read from or written to all at once.

We know that `int` is actually `Int32`, since CLR already ensure operations on `int` are atomic, then why  we need the Interlocked to make sure they are atomic again?

Comment: **Writes** are atomic. If you write an int field, another thread can't read 2 bytes of old value and 2 bytes of new value. A read/modify/write operation is 3 steps however, and those steps together are not atomic.

Comment: @OlivierRogier but this question is really different than the one you post, the one you post ask why Int64 cannot be atomic, my question is why int32 needs interlocked when it is already atomic

Comment: @canton7 thanks for your answer, I'm still a little bit confused, do you mean `_counter++;` is not atomic? I am confused with the wording "atomic", it seems that it has two context meaning, one is as you mentioned  another thread can't read 2 bytes of old value and 2 bytes of new value, the other is read/modify/write operatin can't be interleaved?

Comment: @MarcGravell explained it well in his answer -- read that

Comment: @whoisit no `_counter++` is not atomic; it is `_counter = _counter + 1;` - a read, an increment, and a write; the read and write are *by themselves* atomic, but that doesn't mean that you can compose them together and they continue to be atomic

Comment: @OlivierRogier I don't understand why you go so harsh on me. I did ask some questions, and some bad questions, that's why my previous account get deleted I guess. I did have a couple (6,7) of accounts before (to use in companies I work for to easily login) , and they have been disabled long time ago since at that time I was an junior, asking some native questions. I only had two active accounts in the past 6 months, and they were deleted two.  Now I only have one account. I never have +30 accounts ( I don't even have 10 emails), you just plucked out of the air

Comment: @MarcGravell Oddly enough, the JITters I've looked at do `mov eax, [loc] inc eax mov eax, [loc]` when they could just do `inc [loc]`. But I think you're right and x86 does not guarantee `inc` to be atomic without `lock: ` anyway

Comment: @Charlieface It [uses `inc` for me](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHuGAHKAJYA3bBhgMBAOwwMA+pACu0mFADcXHvSYoGAWQAUASg4aePeRCVioAahvrqZgL40nQA===). .NET Framework x86 [does as well](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAhgZwLYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1MpcoAcAnASwDcUoIlLmCiUA+gGMA9gFcREDgG5mrCtQAslALIAKAJSMVrVpNnyOAagvKSxgL6k7QA)

Comment: @Charlieface it is more about "what is guaranteed" - the fact that it can over-deliver on a lot of modern systems: great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the write is atomic just means that you can't ever see a 3rd value during the update that never existed semantically, that was part (some bytes) from the old value and part (some bytes) from the new value - a torn value. This is an important thing to avoid, but is not the same problem that `Interlocked.Increment` is trying to solve; that is instead trying to prevent *lost updates*, i.e. with two threads:

- (thread A and B both want to increment)
- thread A reads value 3 onto the local stack
- thread B reads value 3 onto the local stack
- thread A increments the local value to get 4
- thread B increments the local value to get 4
- thread A writes the local value to the global, leaving it at 4
- thread B writes the local value to the global, leaving it at 4

here, two threads both thought they incremented the value from 3, yet we only ended up at 4, not the 5 that we would expect from two increments. This is because the *entire operation* is now treated as atomic (how that happens is up to the implementation; it could be a CPU intrinsic, or could be a compare-exchange loop if that isn't available).